# Google Map is not working with .ch or .de but its working with .com

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, geocoding

I am using Google Map Api for getting location based on ZIP codes. 
Its in angularJs.
Its working perfectly when I open the website with `.com` domain.

But when I open it with `.ch` or `.de` domain its showing

> Oops! Some error occured

My implementaion is like this

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This error I m getting in my console : http://prntscr.com/dronsl

Comment: Inspect in your console and you will get a detail error message there. Post that message here.

Comment: That's strange – the Google Maps API documentation says that "Signing up a key for yourdomain.com is usually the best practice, as it will work for all subdomains and directories". Are you sure that you are providing the API key correctly (right keys for the right domains, etc)

Comment: did you try with www?

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458379/google-maps-are-not-showing-with-domainname-com

Comment: with www also its not working.

Comment: Should i need to generate another API Key for all domains ???

Comment: @VikashVerma No you could add multiple domains to the same API key, before that ensure that its the api key which causes the error, You could check that in the web console

Comment: I added `*.domain.com/*` , `*.domain.ch/*` but still its showing referrer http://domail.com/#/ is not allowed.--Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue thaks to @Ramesh, still i m responding to this question. It may help someone else.

The issue was with the API key , I generated a new API key and set the referrer urls while doing so.

Initially it was not working without referrer setting, But now its working fine even if I remove referrers from the API console.